# Anyway to use JAXBIntrospector without class cast conversion for Jaxb unmarshall

Tags: java, jaxb

I like to have no warnings in my code, however this jaxb class , which works well, does give class cast warnings common due to lack of jdk method variant. Is there any way to support all jaxb conversions without getting this warning. I use JAXBIntrospector rather than just Unmarshaller since some jaxb classes only using unmarshaller throws an error on.

here is sample code:

```
public static <T> T unmarshall( final String xml , final Class<T> clazz ) throws Exception
{                                                                                         
    T rtn = null;                                                                         
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;                                                              
    jaxbContext = jaxbContextCache.get( clazz );                                          
    if ( jaxbContext == null )                                                            
    {                                                                                     
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Class.forName( clazz.getName() ) );        
        jaxbContextCache.put( clazz , jaxbContext );                                      
    }                                                                                     
    final Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);                                          
    final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();      
    xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);      
    xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, Boolean.FALSE);                          
    final XMLStreamReader xmlReader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);                  
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();                   
    rtn = (T) JAXBIntrospector.getValue( unmarshaller.unmarshal( xmlReader ) ); // warning cast conversion        
    return rtn;                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the class of `T`, you can unmarshal `JAXBElement<T>` and the return the value. Something along the lines:

```
JAXBElement<T> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, clazz);
return element.getValue();
```

You don't need `JAXBIntrospector` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since `clazz` is of type `Class<T>` you can  use its [`cast(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) 
method instead of using the casting operator `(T)`.

Replace the line

```
rtn = (T) JAXBIntrospector.getValue( unmarshaller.unmarshal( xmlReader ) ); // warning cast conversion
```

by

```
rtn = clazz.cast(JAXBIntrospector.getValue( unmarshaller.unmarshal( xmlReader )));
```

and get rid of the warning about the unchecked cast.